# WebResource.axd - Invalid ViewState

Tags: asp.net, webresource.axd

I keep seeing these errors in our error log.  Any ideas how i can figure out where its coming from, or better yet how to fix the problem?

> System.Web.HttpException: Invalid viewstate. at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.DecryptString(String s) at
>   System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context) at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

**Update**
Here is what I have tried so far - we are running a single web server (no farm)

- Adding a Machine Key value to web.config

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MS has an open bug report as of 6/14/09 reguarding this issue:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=434997&wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: Great link.  Looks like there's much I can do to fix it, just have to hope microsoft comes out with a patch soon.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem when Google (and other search spiders) indexed one of my sites. I had to place in /robots.txt that the webresource.axd files had to be ignored, and the error stopped since.

We are using [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/), so we were able to see the *browser version* that requested the file, and it ended being GoogleBot.

Answer (score 2):

I am having the exact same problem. The bug confirmed by MS (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=434997&wa=wsignin1.0) make sense however, MS claims this is an IE8 issue but I find that users with any version of IE (6,7 & 8) are having this problem.

No Firefox users are experiencing it so it seems to confirm it is a MSIE issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've added the Response headers (ContentType and CharSet) that Microsoft suggested, but still these errors keep coming in.  Thankfully it doesn't appear to make any difference to the end-user, but it's driving me batty seeing these errors in the log.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the error you get when the viewstate can't be decoded - if a request is submitted with someone else's viewstate.

You can duplicate it by recording an asp.net page with wget. Bring that locally saved page up in your browser and click on a link. When it goes to the server, it will try and fail to decode the viewstate in the saved page and you'll see that error.

I ran across this when I was doing some anti-phishing stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Microsoft announced that the following bug fix for IE 8 fixes this problem:
http://blogs.msdn.com/ieinternals/archive/2010/04/01/IE8-Lookahead-Downloader-Fixed.aspx